# How to merge using Meld on Linux

Tags: merge, resolve, conflict, meld

I want to resolve some conflicts of an SVN file using Meld. I'm using the Head version and my version to resolve the conflicts. I am unable to find how to do the merge operation and resolve the conflicts. When i'm right clicking on the line, i just see copy, paste, cut, create patch copy to right, copy to left options. Is there any way to do "Copy this line after mine" or "copy this line before mine" like that?? I used WinMerge when i was working on Windows. Now i moved to a Ubuntu machine and facing this situation for the first time. Please help me how to resolve the conflicts using Meld.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I haven't had much luck doing it nicely on Linux; my experience is that the tools suck, which surprises me.  The extent to which that is a SVN problem, and to which extent it is a tools problem, I am unsure.  I wish you more luck than I've had, fighting the tools.

Comment: Yeah... i installed kdiff3, which seems to be nice. But it is doing this automatic merging which is a headache. Now figuring out how to stop Kdiff to do Automerging. You are soo true about the tools available on Linux.

Comment: It takes a while to get familiar with the tools but when you do, you'll realise their great power and be more efficient than you could with Windows.

Comment: You are really correct. I'm really enjoying linux. But it really takes some time to get familiar with the tools.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Meld 1.4.0 or earlier, you need to hold down `Ctrl` and click on the arrows in the bar between the panes.

With Meld 1.5.0 or later, there are items in the main menu for "Copy above/below left/right" that do what you're looking for. You can also use keyboard shortcuts (`Alt+` `[`, `]`, `;`, and `'`), or use the middle bar as above.

Answer (score 1):

CTRL-click on the arrows

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to do "Copy this line after mine" or "copy this line before mine" like that?

**There's no menu option to do exactly that but it is easily achievable.**

Just select the line / lines from one window and copy (CTRL-C, CTRL-V) to the other window wherever it makes sense

You can also manually add new code to either window.

Meld is a great tool!

Comment: I see those options there. I want to know whether there is any other efficient method to do merging.

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstand me I mean that by selecting the line of text and doing CTRL-C you can copy any line of text from one window and paste it using CTRL-V anywhere in the other window - that answers your question about how to copy lines before / after yours

Comment: yeah. Another doubt. In which file we need to make the changes. There are 3 files, 1. Result file 2. Mine file 3. Head versioned file. In which file we need to copy?

Comment: The head version can't be changed - it's the most recent checkin. You want to update the results file by manually merging changes from your file and the head. It sounds like you're using KDiff now though

Comment: no, i am not using KDiff now. Just tried KDiff. Thank you for your answer. That really helped me.